# Run 2 functions in Javascript inline with ternary operator

Tags: javascript, ternary-operator

I want to run a function and also check if element1 is enabled and if so to disabled it and element2 and the other way around.

```
<input type="" onclick = "function(); element1.disabled==true ? (element1.disabled=false, element2.disabled=false ) : (element1.disabled=true, element2.disabled=true)" />
```

How do i make this code work ?

Since you can't used ";" inside "()" i tried "," but it didn't worked.

Comment: why don't you just call a function that can do the logic ?? declare a function in the same page and then call it : onclick="myFunction()"

Comment: if you declare a function you need to wrap the body with `{` `}` : `function(){...}`, your code  should work

Comment: You also need to replace your semicolons with commas

Comment: @btx9000 I tried with commas, didnt work for me..

Comment: @Hacketo can you please show me ?

Comment: I edited and changed to comma to reflect my code right now

Comment: what is your function name?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case you can use chained assignment:

```
element1.disabled==true ? element1.disabled=element2.disabled=false : element1.disabled=element2.disabled=true
```

Answer (score 2):

There's no need for the ternary operator, you can just negate `element1.disabled`:

```
<input type="checkbox" onclick="element1.disabled = element2.disabled = !element1.disabled" />
```

and you can also chain the assignments (each assignment "returns" the value)

Answer (score 1):

Remove "function()" you don't need that, and replace semicolons to commas. Your code should look like:

```
<input type="button" onclick = "element1.disabled==true ? (element1.disabled=false, element2.disabled=false) : (element1.disabled=true, element2.disabled=true)">
```

Comment: The function() means I also want to run a function in the onclick event along-side the complex if.

Comment: in that case `<input type="button" onclick = "name_of_function(), element1.disabled==true ? (element1.disabled=false, element2.disabled=false) : (element1.disabled=true, element2.disabled=true)">`